# How to control one relay with two arduino boards?

Tags: arduino

So, I got two boards, which both need turn up the light, how should I connect them? I can't use only one board.

Answer (score 4):

If either board can turn the relay on, you can "OR" the two output pins with diodes into the relay.  This would also mean that one Arduino cannot turn the relay OFF if the other one is still ON.

Of course, you should use something to drive the relay -- don't hook it directly to the Arduino:

[image: schematic]

And don't forget the reversed diode across the relay coil.  It will supress the spike when you turn the relay off.  You don't say what relay you're using, but I am assuming it's mechanical, not an SSR (solid state relay).  You wouldn't need that diode if it's an SSR.

If you need *either* one to turn it ON or OFF (either Arduino can *toggle* the light), you will have to connect the relay to just Arduino 1.  Then connect the Arduino 2 to Arduino 1 with a different pin.  Then Arduino 2 can signal Arduino 1 to toggle the relay.  Arduino 1 can toggle the relay without telling Arduino 2 anything.

Comment: Good points by slash-dev.   One question to ask here is what do you really want to do?  If you want to use and XOR (exclusive OR), you could do this with an intermediary TTL 7400 series chip (7486), so only ONE Arduino can turn this on at a time, if that's what you want.  Can you describe the larger sense of what you want to do?  If both Arduinos must be on to give an output, this could be done with two diodes, as in http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs6710/handouts/AppendixB/appendixB.doc2.html